# How much can Airflow scale?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Has anyone reported how much they've been able to get Airflow to scale at their company? I'm looking at implementing Airflow to execute 5,000+ tasks that will each run hourly, and someday scale that up to 20,000+ tasks. In examining the scheduler it looks like that might be a bottleneck since only one instance of it can run, and I'm concerned with that many tasks the scheduler will struggle to keep up. Should I be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We run thousands of tasks a day at my company and have been using Airflow for the  better part of 2 years. These dags run every 15 minutes and are generated through config files that can change at any time (fed in from a UI).

The short answer - yes, it can definitely scale to that, depending on your infrastructure. Some of the new 1.10 features should make this easier than the version of 1.8 we run that runs all those tasks. We ran this on a large Mesos/DCOS that took a good deal of fine tuning to get to a stable point.

The long answer - although it can scale to that, we've found that a better solution is ***multiple Airflow instances*** with different configurations (scheduler settings,number of workers, etc.) optimized for the types dags they are running. A set of DAGs that run long running machine learning jobs should be hosted on an Airflow instance that is different from the ones running 5 minute ETL jobs. This also makes it easier for different teams to maintain the jobs they are responsible for and makes it easier to iterate on any fine tuning that's needed.

Comment: Note though that there is a key dependency in Airflow that *doesn't* scale - the scheduler. You can't use multiple schedulers for different DAGs, so the only option for running a scheduler is a massive instance is vertical scaling. Until there is a good option for this, using multiple Airflow instances will be the best option for scaling.

Comment: Good thoughts, thank you. When running multiple Airflow instances, have you encountered a case where you want a DAG running in one Airflow instance to be a dependency for a DAG in a separate Airflow instance, or do you keep them largely independent?

Comment: Generally speaking, we try to keep them independent of another. However, if something like that is required, we might have a task in Airflow A output a file in an external file store (e.g. S3) and have a DAG in Airflow B with a sensor that waits for that file

Comment: What kind of backend are you guys using for the Airflow for helping it scale to thousands of tasks? We use a MySQL backend and are hitting the limits of CPU/connection spikes when a thousand tasks start around the same time.